# How much damage does Great Lightning Spear do? (PvE)

Tags: dark-souls-2

Assuming a player were to have exactly 42 Faith (The base requirement of the spell) and using a basic Chime (Miracle Catalyst) with no buffs against an enemy with little/no resistance to the spell, how much damage would Great Lightning Spear do?

I've seen the spell a couple of times, and it was doing quite a fair amount of damage, but I could never tell if the player using it just had nothing but Faith leveled. I've checked the wiki, but they never list the amount of damage spells do at base requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience I would say around 700 damage based on the hypothetical character you stated but I can't say for certain. The best way to test it would be to use a [Soul Vessel](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Vessel) and respect your character then test it on the Undead Hollows in the Forest of The Fallen Giants

Comment: Are you sure? That seems like an awful lot of damage, even compared to what should be a higher level of the spell, Soul Spear. In fact, it's almost comparable to Crystal Soul Spear, which takes 53 Intelligence, not 42, and has far fewer casts!